# How vue.js cli command "npm run serve" work

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

After running `npm run serve` it gives an address like `http://localhost:8080` and it works, this address is targeted the root folder of local server but my project exists another folder like `http://localhost/vue`

And my question is how the address `http://localhost:8080` works and where is the actual `index.html`? Since my actual project placed in `localhost/vue` folder! and the address should be http://localhost/vue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused on what is going on in the background when you use serve.

When you are running the command `npm run serve`, your project is getting built by Webpack and then "served" via a local http-server. This server is using your project's build folder as it's root.

It seems like you have created a folder named `localhost` as out of your comments here. [`http://localhost`](http://localhost) is not a folder called "localhost" in your computer. In fact, it is just a name for your internal ip: [127.0.0.1](http://127.0.0.1). You can test this by going to [127.0.0.1:8080](http://127.0.0.1:8080) and seeing this is the same as [http://localhost:8080](https://localhost:8080)

in programmatic terms, one could say the following:
`localhost == 127.0.0.1`

That out of the way, you seemt to also expect there to be a sub-folder named `vue`, since that's what you have in your `localhost` folder. Knowing the above; [`http://localhost`](http://localhost) is not a folder `localhost` on your pc. It is however the folder the http-server has chosen, in this case, vue chooses the folder `/dist` inside your project folder.

Example: Your project folder has the following path: `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\myProject`

When you then run `npm run serve` in that folder, the vue http-server will serve (host) the folder `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\myProject\dist`

This means `http://localhost == C:\Users\Admin\Documents\myProject\dist\index.html`

However, if your goal here is to have your project served as: [`http://localhost/my-custom-sub-folder`](http://localhost/my-custom-sub-folder)

You will have to edit the vue.config.js for your vue project by adding: [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

vue.config.js example:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/my-custom-sub-folder',
};
```

Comment: I think this needs some correction. Dev server files are stored in memory in default unless you set a specific path for the compiled files.

Answer (score 0):

the index.html file should be by default placed at the root of your project in the "public" folder

Comment: do you know vue.js

Comment: kindof I'm starting using it with django to build SPA, it's pretty straightforward btw, I don't know what you don't understand, is it your first time working with a local server ? because it doesn't really make sense

Comment: but that is not the answer i expected

Comment: Your question doesn't make sens, you can run npm run serve -- --port 3000 for example if you want to access your project through another port. Seems you don't unserstand how vuejs is working, read the doc, you could choose to use vuerouter when creating your project tho, that way you could access different endpoints pretty easily

Comment: i am new in vue.js, i want to know that my vue.js project is inside a folder named vue, so the address should be http://localhost:8080/vue but it runs in http://localhost:8080 how?

Comment: I understand what you say, and no the address shouldn't be localhost:8080/vue. What are you trying to do ?  Read vue cli and vuejs doc, when you first create your project  choose to use vue router when asked to, then you'll be able to access different endpoints like localhost:8080/about corresponding to different components. The vue cli boilerplate is pretty verbose, it shouldn't be hard to understand if you went through vuejs documentation